# C#: substituting a subclass/subtype of a parameter when overiding a method like Java do?

Tags: java, c#, oop, interface

In java, i can do this:

```
public class A {
    //...
}

public class B extends A {
    //...
}

public interface I {
    void test(A a);
}

public class C implements I {
    //i can use class B as parameters in java but how to do in .net ?
    // not work in .net
    @override
    public void test(B b){

    }
}
```

I can use class B as parameters in java but how to do in .net ?

Comment: this wouldn't even work in java, for implementing `I` , test parameter type must be `A`.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if that were allowed in Java, as that would break the contract of the interface.

Comment: `public void test(A a){/*do something*/}` is the only option available to class C. Without public keyword, there will be compile-time error.

Comment: @Saurav Sahu sorry about that,i forgeted `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement the interface member `I.test(A a)`, the the `test()` method of the `C` must be public, non-static, and have the same name and signature as the interface member.

`C.test` fails one criterion: it does not have the same signature as `I.test`.

---

#### Option 1: Implement the Interface

```
public class A {
    //...
}

public class B extends A {
    //...
}

public interface I {
    void test(A a);
}

public class C implements I {
    public void test(A a){

    }
}
```

of course you can still pass `B` instances into `C.test`:

```
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
c.test(b);//works just fine
```

#### Option 2: Change the Interface

Say your implementation of `I` in `C` depends on a property present on `B` but not on `A`.  Suppose further that it makes sense that `I.test` is a perfectly valid method to write so long as the parameter being passed in extends `A`.

In that scenario, you can try something like this:

```
public class A
{
    //...
}

public class B : A
{
    //...
}

public interface I<T> where T : A
{
    void test(T a);
}

public class C : I<B>
{
    public void test(B b)
    {

    }
}
```

Which utilizes [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) as well as [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) and seems like it may be a little closer to what you are trying to represent/accomplish.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please take a look at   [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)   which details some key guidelines. :-)